# Custom fonts in Github's markdown (like README.md)?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to use custom fonts with github's markdown? I'm currently loading an image as a logo, yet rendering a font would be faster and nicer.

Comment: In normal markdown you can use inline HTML, like `<span style="font-family: 'Lucida Console';">foo</span>`, however it seems that the github markdown parser strips these tags out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> rendering a font would be faster and nicer.

Yes, except you wound not use any (multiple) colors in said "icon as a font".
See "[GitHub redesigns its icons using a custom font](http://blog.horizon-nigh.org/post/22761621054/github-redesigns-its-icons-using-a-custom-font)"

> You can, of course, take a monotone font-rendered icon and set its colour to, for example, red or blue, but that changes the entire icon; you can’t have different parts of the icon use different colours, or use shading

(example of [CSS effects for Icon Font here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/), from the [Trello article](http://blog.fogcreek.com/trello-uses-an-icon-font-and-so-can-you/))

But, as far as I can see ([Markdown Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet), and [Markdown Help](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown)), no, you cannot have a custom font.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a custom font, just generate it with https://github.com/crocodilejs/custom-fonts-in-emails and then you can just put the image/upload it to GitHub readme.

Comment: Not a great idea for anyone who has any kind of vision impairment, not does it scale well for different devices or even monitor resolutions.