# How to write urdu langage font in Github README.md file

Tags: github, unicode, fonts, character-encoding, urdu

I'm not able to write urdu language in Github README.md file. if I am pasting urdu copied content into README.md file then content is overlaping

I have copied content in urdu [https://www.write-urdu.com/urdu-editor.html](https://stackoverflow.com) editor & pasted back to readme.md file but still content is overlapping.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "overlapping?" My initial experiments show this appearing in Arabic/Persian script rather than Urdu/Nastaliq script, but I don't see any overlap. Is this your problem? https://gist.github.com/rnapier/eea36daa2595545ac88f227285bb9b0c

Comment: Since Nastaliq is considered a font issue rather than a character issue in Unicode, I don't believe this can be done without a font (as you suggest), and I don't believe anything has changed about that being unsupported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846457/custom-fonts-in-githubs-markdown-like-readme-md

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have opened README.md file in my vscode there i'm pasting urdu lang content. when i'm moving curson from right to left direction to go end of the line then its not moving also content are mxing on moving cursor position.